# Estimating Frechet distribution parameter in R

Tags: r, distributions

I have a data set with 925 members that using Easyfit, I've determined is best fit using a Frechet distribution. Now, I'm trying to replicate this functionality in R to determine the optimum fit parameters using the VGAM package. Using this code:

```
vglm(V1 ~1, frechet2(location = 0), data, trace = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : initial values for 'location' are out of range
```

As I'm trying to estimate the 2-parameter distribution the location should be 0 (correct?)

In the VGAM documentation it mentions that the package may fail for low values of shape parameter (near 2 or lower); however, in EasyFit the estimation shows the shape parameter at .2646. Any thoughts on how I should handle this? I've done a search on but haven't found any other packages that provide the same functionality.

Comment: What is the minimum value in the dataset?  If it is negative, then a location of $0$ is invalid.

Comment: I get a general sense of unease and doom when people talk about choosing a distribution simply because it "best fits the data."

Comment: What's "EasyFit"? Sounds like it should be called "FarTooEasyFit"...

Comment: @whuber The minimum value is 0, there are no negative values.

Comment: @ColinK I understand this isn't the optimum method but since I have 425,000 different datasets that I need to fit a distribution to I'm tying to find an automated method for doing so.

Comment: @Spacedman Easyfit is a product from Mathwave

Comment: But why are you trying to fit distributions in the first place?  What is your goal?

Comment: @BenBolker The project is to take a set of event arrival times and find the most appropriate distribution to use in finding the probability of another event at a specific point in the future. Each of the data sets are unique and independent from the others but represent natural events and thus fit within the same general constraints. I'm sorry if I'm being obtuse, I'm not really a statistician, merely a database developer that got roped into this project and I'm still trying to find my feet.

Comment: Sorry if you're stuck with a problem description that you can't change, but ... most statisticians (I don't quite count, but there are lots here on SE) would be horrified (see comments above) at this approach.  Rather than matching to a specified (if large) set of parametric distributions, I would recommend a nonparametric approach like log-spline density estimation ... you might get some interesting answers if you asked the question "what's the best statistical method for making robust, accurate, automated predictions of future event probabilities given 500-1000 samples of event times?"

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, that's a great suggestion, I'll have to dig a little further and see what I can come up with.